# Template SFINAE for a range of values to generate only 2 classes

Tags: c++, sfinae

I am trying to program a bitset like class that uses internally an `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` member variable for storage, depending of specific length in bits.

Of course it is possible to do this easily using SFINAE with spetialization, `std::enable_if`, `std::conditional`... in a template (please note pseudocode):

```
template <int N>
struct bitset
{
    static constexpr int bits = N;
    uint32_t value;//if N <=32 use 32 bits variable
    //uint64_t value;
};
```

Problem with this approach is that there are al least as many classes as variables defines, p.g. this will return **false**:

```
std::is_same<bitset<1>, bitset<2>>::value
```

What I am wondering if is there is some way to implement `bitset` in a way which only generates these two final classes:

```
template <int bits>
struct bitset;

struct bitset32
{
    explicit bitset32(int _bits) : bits(_bits) { }
    
    int bits;
    uint32_t value;
};

struct bitset64
{
    explicit bitset64(int _bits) : bits(_bits) { }
    
    int bits;
    uint64_t value;
};
```

Aiming to reduce the total number of generted clases and a common interface for them.

**EDIT AND FEASIBLE SOLUTION:**

Answered by user Igor Tandetnik (merits to him).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct bitset32
{
    explicit bitset32(int _bits) : bits(_bits) { }
    
    int bits;
    uint32_t value;
};

struct bitset64
{
    explicit bitset64(int _bits) : bits(_bits) { }
    
    int bits;
    uint64_t value;
};

template <int N>
using bitset = std::conditional_t<(N<=32), bitset32, bitset64>;


struct telegram
{
    bitset<5> var1;
    bitset<6> var2;
    bitset<32> var3;
    bitset<64> var4;
    bitset<85> var5;
};

 
int main ()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<bitset<5>, bitset<6>>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<bitset<32>, bitset<33>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `template <int N> using bitset=std::conditional_t<(N<=32), bitset32, bitset64>` Is this what you are looking for, by any chance?

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Oh yes, it does exactly fit when I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: Better to use the answer part, than edit question to show the answer. (Self answering is fine, asking for the commenter if (s)he want to do the answer might be better first :-) ).

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: your solution looks fine, Would you like to make a formal answer to this question?

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't pass `N` to the constructor of `bitset32` / `bitset64`. I can't think of any magic that would a) make `bitset<X>` and `bitset<Y>` be the same type as determined by `std::is_same`, but at the same time b) have them behave differently at run-time when default-constructed. You could make `bitset<N>` a proper class template derived from `bitset32` or `bitset64` using the same `std::conditional` trick. They would be distinct classes, but with almost no code in them.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: `make_bitset<N>()` might "resolve" the issue.